# How to get the events of current week in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I've implemented the fullCalendar in week view. I have added few events in it. Now I am trying to duplicate those events in other weeks, on click of some external button. Follow is the screenshot of currently implemented fullcalendar:

[image]

As you can see that there is a button of duplicate, on top-right corner of fullcalendar. On click of it I need to get all the event of the week that is being displayed in this week.

Following is how I have initialized the fullcalendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
      left: options["is_staff"] == true ? 'today prev,next' : '',
      center: '',
      right: '',
  },
  firstDay: 0,
  editable: true,
  selectable: true,
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  weekNumbers: true,
  eventOverlap: false,
  events: events_data
})
```

Following is my script for button click:

```
$("#dup-week-schedule").click(function(){
    var currentWeek = $.fullCalendar.formatDate($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'), "W");
    var currentWeekArray = [];
    var currentWeekTitleArray = [];        $.each($('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents'), function(i,v){
      if ((v['start'].isoWeek()) == currentWeek){
        currentWeekArray.push(v);
        currentWeekTitleArray.push(v['title']);
      }
    });
}
```

The issue is according the fullcalendar that is displayed in image, 22/04 should be included in current week. But it is being excluded from current week and the next sunday is being included in current week.

Comment: $.fullCalendar.formatDate is deprecated (unless you're using fullCalendar v1) and may not work reliably. You should be using momentJS functions for date and time related operations. I would expect `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').isoWeek()` to get you the current week. However, as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date, ISO weeks start on a Monday, which probably explains your issue. You might be better to fetch the current view and get the actual start and end dates of it, and filter your events that way instead.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the response. I will surely try it and let you know about my output.